# In Container.php line 767: Class mailer does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpmailer

I am very new to PHP, can someone help me to fix this issue. When i run the command composer install, I am getting this error.

> [2020-12-08 10:28:26] production.ERROR: Class mailer does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class mailer does not exist at /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:767)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(767): ReflectionClass->__construct('mailer')
> #1 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('mailer')
> #2 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('mailer', Array)
> #3 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('mailer', Array)
> #4 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1210): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('mailer')
> #5 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(161): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('mailer')
> #6 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(130): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance('mailer')
> #7 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(217): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
> #8 /var/www/cachet/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(83): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
> #9 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(314): CachetHQ\Cachet\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(ErrorException))
> #10 /var/www/cachet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(118): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->reportException(Object(ErrorException))
> #11 /var/www/cachet/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
> #12 {main}
> "}

Comment: What is "this error"? Can you share more details, like the code involved?

Comment: Delete the "vendor" folder then run `composer install`

Comment: Solved by downgrading the composer version.